# Preventing user from inputting integers to string variables in C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, properties, try-catch

If I write the following code (inside the Main method):

```
Console.Write("First name: ");
student.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
```

where FirsName is a property of Student class, how can I prevent the user from entering integer characters? Can this be done using try-catch block?

Comment: Unless you write your own `Console.ReadLine()` and filter each key you can't. But you can check after reading the line for integers using `char.IsDigit()` and prompting again if the check fails.

Comment: The cynic in me wants to say that as soon as you implement this, some user is going to come along with the name `7` and have problems using your application.

Comment: @itsme86 the thing is that a user may accidentally(or not) input a number so the developer should be able to prevent that and display an appropriate message instead of letting the system crash

Comment: Why would a number in a string cause the system to crash? I could see a character in a number causing a crash, but wouldn't expect the other to cause problems.

Comment: Yeah, right. The system doesn't crash but it doesn't make sense if the user inputs a number and the program continues to run without displaying any message about that. If you see real programs that ask for user input they would normally prevent entering numbers while writing sb's name. You can take this case as an example. I'll implement this kind of code inside my program anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not very specific, but based on the data you gave you can do something like this using `try catch`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        try
        {
            Console.Write("First name: ");
            student.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            ValidateMyString(student.FirstName);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    static void ValidateMyString(string s)
    {
        if (s.Any(char.IsDigit))
        {
            throw new FormatException();
        }
    }
}
```

[Here a example in dotnetfiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qC9OwX)

Comment: it seems like it's fine at first, but it always throws the error even if i enter only letters

Comment: Checki it now @EmptyName

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent user from "entering" Numeric Characters, you could do the following.

```
var value = new StringBuilder();
var run = true;
while (run)
{
    var inputKey = Console.ReadKey(true);
    switch (inputKey.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.Enter:
            run = false;
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
            value.Append(inputKey.KeyChar);
            break;
        default:
            if (!char.IsDigit(inputKey.KeyChar))
                value.Append(inputKey.KeyChar);
            Console.Write(inputKey.KeyChar);
            break;
    }

}

var name = value.ToString();
```